# Loop though PivotTables to Relink to PowerPivot table

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

I have a document of PivotTables all generated from one PowerPivot table.

I realized at the last minute that there was something wrong with my data in this PowerPivot table and had to change the original source file for the PowerPivot table. I have now imported that new table.

Is there any way (VBA is allowed here) that I can relink all of the PivotTables in my document to this new table without having to go through every single PivotTable manually?

Someone has suggested to me

```
For each sheet in activesheet.sheets
For each pivot_table in sheet.pivottables 
pivot_table.changepivotcache activeworkbook.pivotcaches.create([sourcetype],[NEW datasource],[version])
Next
Next
```

but I have doubts that this will work, since PowerPivot tables are not conventional Excel tables.

Comment: Can't you edit the original table?

Comment: @Jacob - I am trying that, but it is quite difficult when you have about 5 million records and not enough RAM to copy/paste all of those without crashing. This would involve copying/pasting at least 4 columns with 5 million records.

Comment: Pasting that amount of data in is not a good idea :-)

Comment: @Jacob - Probably not. :P